# Excel ISERROR formula returns #VALUE! even when I'm using IF function to return blank

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I'm using an excel formula to check for 3 different conditions when, if any one of the three are met, should return a blank cell. Even though one of the 3 conditions is being met, it still returns a #VALUE! cell which I do not want. Here is the formula:

```
=IF(OR(BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID")="#N/A Field Not Applicable",[@CUSIP]="", ISERROR(BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID"))=TRUE),"",BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID")/100)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this `ISERROR(BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID"))=TRUE)` is `TRUE` then `BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID")="#N/A Field Not Applicable"` will return an error and error the whole formula.

Comment: If the Bloomberg Add-In function BDP returns an error string other than "#N/A Field Not Applicable" instead of an error value (#NA or #ERROR) , this OR will be FALSE. And the second BDP function call's string value can not be divided by 100.

Comment: one way to debug excel error is break down the formula into multiple cell, for example, you can write the whole or statement into another cell and then use that cell value in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(OR([@CUSIP]="",IFERROR(BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID")="#N/A Field Not Applicable",TRUE)),"",BDP(A18&" CUSIP", "YLD_CUR_MID")/100)
```